# Given values for p, q and e, but gcd(e,phi) is not 1, then how to find n & d in RSA? Or is it even possible?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

The values are: **p = 19**, **q = 23**, and **e = 3**.
Calculating as per the algorithm: **n = 437** & ***phi = 396***.
But I don't think RSA is valid here becasue ***GCD(e, phi) is not 1 in this case, as GCD(3, 396) = 3***.
So, that means RSA algorithm isn't satisfied and can't be proceeded further to calculate d, right?

**I'd like to ask** if I am correct in assuming that there is no solution for those given values of p, q and e due to GCD(e,phi) = 1 not being satisfied.

Or am I doing something wrong here?
This is the original question which appeared in a previous examination paper that I'm solving: *(word by word)*

```
In RSA, given p=19, q=23 and e=3, find n and d.
```

I'm willing to assume its a tricky question which checks whether one knows the algorithm(and its steps) or not. Please let me know if my assumption is right or not, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  Running the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers) to compute ModInv(3, 396) we get

```
ModInverse(3, 396)
  r=396, newR=3, t=0, newT=   1
  r=  3, newR=0, t=1, newT=-132

  newR == 0 && r > 0: Not Invertible.
```

Therefore there's no value for `d`.  (Computing it against `lambda(n)` instead of `phi(n)` also produces "Not invertible", since lambda is just phi/2 and 3 is the prime factor that broke things.)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I did some _googling_ later to see if there is any way to cross check using some in-built Java functions. Figured out Using BigInteger and trying to assign the value:

`BigInteger d = e.modInverse(phi)` results in a ArithmeticException saying BigInteger not invertible.

Which confirms what I was assuming and what you elaborated upon. Thanks again! :)